# Code snippet. If in front of switch-statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement

I've got code like this:

```
if (pref_const == Constants.PREF_PricingTypesFormWidth)
{
    a = 2;
    b = 3;   
    DoneFlag = true;
}
if (pref_const == Constants.PREF_PricingTypesFormTop)
{
    a = 4;
    b = 2; 
    DoneFlag = true;
}
......
if(!DoneFlag)//replacing of default-section in switch-statement
{
    //DoSthng
}
```

And many many other if-statements. Don't ask me why do not to use switch-statement. 
So, is there any way to reduce the DoneFlag variable at all??

Comment: Do you want to **reuse** or **reduce** `DoneFlag`? I don't really understand your question.

Comment: I did not get your question. What is the last sentence supposed to mean?

Comment: If you ask a question which makes heavy demands on the reader just to understand the question, don't be surprised if nobody answers.

Comment: no switch, no else if, what will you want to do at all?

Comment: Ok, I had to answer (below). If you do a little research on polymorphism, you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize your solution slightly so Done flag value will be set in single line only, all other would stay as is. Is it fine for you?

LINQ [Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
using System.Linq;

// Assuming constants are strings
IList<string> constants = new List<string> 
           {
              Constants.PREF_PricingTypesFormWidth,
              Constants.PREF_PricingTypesFormTop,
           };

bool DoneFlag = constants.Any(p => p == perf_const);
```

[Enumerable.Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

> Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "reduce" you mean "eliminate", a logically equivalent chain of nested `if-then-else` statements that does not use the `DoneFlag` is as follows:

```
if (pref_const == Constants.PREF_PricingTypesFormWidth)
{
    a = 2;
    b = 3;   
}
else // <<===
if (pref_const == Constants.PREF_PricingTypesFormTop)
{
    a = 4;
    b = 2; 
}
else //replacing of default-section in switch-statement
{
    //DoSthng
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use polymorphism: let each concrete class set variables, so your consuming code doesn't know or care which class is doing it.

Note: This answer is intentionally short because of your accept rate.